# Shell Programming for launchd

Tags: macos, bash, shell, stdout, launchd

I have been shell scripting (in this case *bash*) for years, and am quite comfortable doing it.  However I have just written a shell script that I want to run via `launchd`.  Now with most shell scripts I have written redirection and the `echo`ing of variables (memory resident information) to file, is something that I would have thought would have to happen fairly regularly.  Things like:

## create a line in a log file:

`echo "${DATESTAMP} ${INPUT}" >> "$LOGFILE"`

## or, after working out a value add it to a file

`echo "${MY_EXTIP}" > "${CURRENT_IP}"`

## or, create a file with the PID of a process for monitoring

`echo "${SSH_TUN_IP}" > "${SSH_PIDFILE}"`

However launchd seems to *steal* stdout (and stderr, but stderr isn't important to this), making this seemingly impossible.  Now this might be a great time for me to learn python or perl to get around this, but I thought people must actually have an answer for how to do this in bash.

TL;DR, how do i get memory resident information to a file in bash when run from launchd

Any help greatly appreciated.
c

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to steal"?

Comment: This article ( http://erikslab.com/2011/02/04/logging-with-launchd/ ) may be of some help.

Comment: [in reply to John Hascall] yeah, have seen that page already in looking for answers, it allows you to take the log file example (the first of my examples) and make it a non-issue, but doesn't help with the second or third examples (which are functionally the same, finding a value, and entering the data into a file)

Comment: [in reply to chepner]  
From the launchd man page:

StandardOutPath <string>
     This optional key specifies what file should be used for data being sent to stdout when using stdio(3).

which then means something like this:
# echo "fred" > /tmp/myfile

doesn't work

Comment: It does not have to mean _something like # echo "fred" > /tmp/myfile doesn't work_, since new redirections reopen `stdout` and override the previous one made by `launchd`. Did you actually try it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: send echo output to a file descriptor rather than redirecting stdout to file as control applications (launchd in this case) could have already closed/redirected stdout/stderr.

Basically one could:

```
exec 3> ${LOGFILE}     # Associate file descriptor 3 to LOGFILE
echo "my message" >&3  # Write to file descriptor 3
exec 3>&-              # Close file descriptor 3
```